# Store contact form information to a class in JavaScript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, class, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to build a JS application that instantiates new contact object when the form is filled. However, when it comes to classes I am struggling to create logic between getting the input fields and instantiating the contact.

Code so far.

Class to create contact on click.

```
export class Create {

    addEventListeners () {
        document.querySelector('#new-contact').addEventListener("click", createContact);
    }

    createContact () {
        let contact = new Contact({
            contFn: 'Tim',
            contLn: 'Cook'
        })
    }

}
```

Class for the contact.

```
'use strict';

export class Contact {

    constructor (contFn, contLn, contEmail, contPhone, contSocial) {
        this.contFn = contFn;
        this.contLn = contLn;
        this.contEmail = contEmail;     
        this.contPhone = contPhone;
        this.contSocial = contSocial;
    }

    printContact () {
        console.log(this.contFn);
        console.log(this.contLn);
    }

}

window.addEventListener('load', () => new Contact());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createContact` is undefined. There is no variable with that name. It's a method, a property inherited from the prototype of the instances. You have to access it as `this.createContact`. But assuming you are using the `Create` instance inside the method, you can't just pass it around without [losing context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572), so you should do

```
addEventListeners () {
    document.querySelector('#new-contact').addEventListener("click", (e) => this.createContact(e));
}
```

Notice that you probably shouldn't use a `class` here if it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Would `this.discasrd = this.createContact.bind(this);` in the constructor have the same desired affect as `addEventListener("click", (e) => this.createContact(e));`?

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well, it would be `….addEventListener("click", this.discasrd)` then